# Selection not being triggered on iPhone (works on iPad)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm getting a strange behaviour from my application, I have two storyboards files, one for iPad and another for iPhone, inside my storyboard I have an UIViewController with a TableView
from the storyboard I just selected the prototype cell and added a selection call to another UIViewController using the push type of action.

Every time I click on my cells testing my app using any iPad I have here with me everything occurs as expected, but when I start to test my app in any iPhone (5,4,3GS) my table just don't execute the selection.

As I seted my selection to execute a push to another segue I have some logic running on:

```
-(BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender;
```

This line is called on iPad but not in the iPhone

Here is a picture from the connections I have in my UITableView in the iPhone storyboard
[image: iPhone UITableView storyboard]

As you can see the connections are the same in my iPad storyboard
[image: iPad UITableView storyboard]

And here are my cell triggered selection calling another UIViewController, first one is from my iPhone storyboard and the other is from my iPad storyboard:

[image: Cell iPhone storyboard] [image: Cell iPad storyboard]

To help you to compare my storyboard here is my Controller code from storyboards:

**iPhone**

```
<tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" allowsSelectionDuringEditing="YES" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="6Gg-eR-53c">
    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="89" width="320" height="479"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
    <prototypes>
        <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" accessoryType="disclosureIndicator" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="LojaCell" id="eyH-Fu-fm7">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="22" width="320" height="44"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="eyH-Fu-fm7" id="28k-dO-gBn">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="287" height="43"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <connections>
                <segue destination="fFu-DS-IBm" kind="push" identifier="LojaSegue" id="4OD-1C-Xow"/>
            </connections>
        </tableViewCell>
    </prototypes>
    <connections>
        <outlet property="dataSource" destination="HDd-qp-Vu5" id="hjd-eg-wpV"/>
        <outlet property="delegate" destination="HDd-qp-Vu5" id="iFo-Pa-mRI"/>
    </connections>
</tableView>
```

**iPad**

```
<tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" allowsSelectionDuringEditing="YES" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="a6a-h4-Inj">
    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="89" width="768" height="935"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
    <prototypes>
        <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" accessoryType="disclosureIndicator" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="LojaCell" id="VK3-l3-sLl">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="22" width="768" height="44"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="VK3-l3-sLl" id="1rm-J3-M5W">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="735" height="43"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                </tableViewCellContentView>
                <connections>
                    <segue destination="OwK-Um-sM3" kind="push" identifier="LojaSegue" id="WS4-PJ-fRi"/>
                </connections>
        </tableViewCell>
    </prototypes>
    <connections>
       <outlet property="dataSource" destination="KHn-sS-4WW" id="ee7-mU-vak"/>
       <outlet property="delegate" destination="KHn-sS-4WW" id="mlp-jH-KfD"/>
    </connections>
</tableView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was with my XCode, don't know why but sometimes XCode build simple doesn't work, I just found the solution to my problem here:     [How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4)

Also, if someone think this question need to be deleted since the problem wasn't what was described first just let a comment here and I will delete the question.